# Check if file exists or not in KORN Shell

Tags: unix, ksh

I want to check if file exists are not in a Korn shell, but not able to get a proper documentation for that. I have the following code that checks if file exists and is of size zero. If the file size is more than zero it returns false.

```
if [[ ! -s ${abs_file_name} ]]
```

I need a list of possible options (like -s, -e, -x, etc like in the above example) with description to check if file exists in KORN shell, NOT BASH shell.

Comment: Try `man test` and look for `-f`.

Comment: That's a great suggestion.. looks like this command gives exactly the same output from ksh shell as well as bash shell ! So does it mean the file compare flags in the 'if' loop is same in both type of shells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a node exists with

```
if [ -e "${abs_file_name}" ]
```

You can check if a node is a file.

```
if [ -f "${abs_file_name}" ]
```

This does something dumb if `abs_file_name` resolves to a symlink to a file.

Also: `-d` for directory, `-r` for you can read it, `-x` for executable.